# Mongodb, child model validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a profile model and it embeds_one kids_type and parent_type. As you can see in below code.

I want to validate kids_type child model. After using validates_associated, it's working fine for me.But problem is that, it validates kids_type model [#, @messages=**{:kids_type=>["is invalid"]}>**]  , instead i am expecting field wise error, As i need to display inline error...

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates_associated :kids_type  
  # PROFILE TYPE KIDS & PARENT
  embeds_one :kids_type, :class_name => "ProfileKidsType"
  embeds_one :parent_type, :class_name => "ProfileParentType"
end

class ProfileType
  include Mongoid::Document

  #COMMON FILES FOR KIDS AND PARENT
  field :fname, :type => String
  field :lname, :type => String

  validates_presence_of :fname, :message => "ERROR: First name is required"
  validates_presence_of :lname, :message => "ERROR: Last name is required"
end

class ProfileParentType < ProfileType
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, :type => String  
  embedded_in :profile, :inverse_of => :parent_type
end

class ProfileKidsType < ProfileType
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :nickname, :type => String
  embedded_in :profile, :inverse_of => :kids_type
end
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here @profile is instance of Profile, it will give you all errors field wise for kids type

```
@profile.kids_type.errors
```